# How to write methods inside JSP and call them?

Tags: jsp

Following is my jsp code. I'm new to JSP. I get the error shown after the code

```
<body>
<%!
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Leg>> trip;
    public void routeManager(){
        Location stLoc = new Location(60.2040521,24.96185113,"1023");
        Location endLoc = new Location(60.17936316, 24.92282214 ,"1130");
        RouteRetriever hrr = new RouteRetriever();
        trip = hrr.getRoutes(stLoc, endLoc, false);
    }
%>
<%  routeManager();
    System.out.println("Im here AA");%>
<%= out.println("Hello World:"+hrr.size()) %>
<p>Booooooooooooo!</p>
</body>
```

Error:

```
An error occurred at line: 30 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
The method print(boolean) in the type JspWriter is not applicable for the arguments (void)
```

Comment: is this code compiles ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should change

```
<%= out.println("Hello World:"+hrr.size()) %>
```

to (just output)

```
<%= "Hello World:"+trip.size() %>
```

or if you want to use println (change <%= to <%):

```
<% out.println("Hello World:"+hrr.size()); %>
```

Comment: But try to avoid functions and scriplets usage in jsp. Please create your custom tags for this.

Comment: Semicolon is missing at the end of `out.println`

Answer (score 0):

`<%=%>` and `out.println` does not go together.

Change

To

```
<% out.println("Hello World:"+hrr.size()); %>
```

`<%=%>` is a short hand converted into `out.write` when Jsp page is compiled